# PHP and AJAX not working together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble with making a deleting system in PHP,Javascript and AJAX. I've done it before but this time *PHP and AJAX won't make contact, nor will the Javascript script do anything.*

In the Javascript file(*server-log.js*) alerting something won't work, it will not come. This also won't work for the AJAX/PHP handler file(*server-log.handler.php*).
The **console bug** doesn't give any bugs in return, the URLs in all the files are also correct. That's because I can find every file with the console bug from Chrome

The JS script(server-log.js):

```
    $('.btn btn-xs btn-danger').click(function(){

    var press = $.this.attr('id');
    var press_url = 'action=delete&id='+press;

        $.ajax({
            type:       'POST',
            url:        'panel/includes/handlers/server-log.handler.php',
            data:       press_url,
            success:    function(responseText)
            {
                $.parseJSON(responseText);

                    /* If and else controlling system  */
                    if(responseText.indexOf(1) > -1)
                    {
                        $("#danger").append('<strong>Helaas!</strong> Het is niet gelukt om de gevraagde log rij te verwijderen');
                    }
                    else if(responseText.indexOf(2) > -1)
                    {
                        $("#danger").append('<strong>Helaas!</strong> Het opgegeven ID nummer is niet geldig');
                    }
                    else if(reponseText.indexOf(100) > -1)
                    {
                        $("#success").append('<strong>Goed!</strong> De gevraagde log is succesvol verwijderd');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#info").append('<strong>Info:</strong> Er is helaas een onbekende fout opgetreden <i>2255200914</i>');
                    }
            }
        });
});
```

The HTML part(server-log.php)

```
                    <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;" id="success"></div>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none"; id="danger"></div>
                    <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;" id="info"></div>
                <div class="error-log sscroll">
                <ul>
                <form method="post">
                <?php
                while($arrayLogs = $arrayqLogs->fetch_array())
                {
                ?>
                    <li>
                    <span class="green">[<?php echo $arrayLogs['date']; ?>]</span> 
                    <span class="red">[<?php echo $arrayLogs['action']; ?>]</span> 
                    [<?php echo $arrayLogs['name']; ?>] <?php echo $arrayLogs['url']; ?> 
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" name="deleting" id="<?php echo $arrayLogs['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </li>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                </form>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

The PHP handler part(server-log.handler.php)

```
    <?php
include_once '../config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'delete')
    {
        $intAction      = trim($_POST['id']);
        $error          = array();
        $bolean         = false;

            # Prepared statement
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,name,action,url,date FROM logs WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $intAction);
            $stmt->execute();
            $intStatement = $stmt->num_rows();
            $stmt->close;

                /* Controlling part */
                if($intStatement == 0)
                {
                    $error[]    = 1;
                    $bolean     = true;
                }
                elseif(!ctype_digit($intAction))
                {
                    $error[]    = 2;
                    $bolean     = true;
                }
                    // Deleting and notifying
                    if($bolean == false)
                    {
                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM logs WHERE id = ?");
                        $stmt->bind_param('i', $intAction);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();

                            # Returning error code
                            $error[]    = 100;
                    }

            /* Returning the value in a readable way */
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($error);
    }
?>
```

So this isn't the first time I'm making this on my website, but I haven't done it often either so I think I've done many things wrong. I'm thanking you guys in advance for helping, English isn't BTW my mother tongue so sorry for any grammar/misspelled words.

Comment: Did you find the point where `console.log()` stops responding?

Comment: Why are you performing a `SELECT` query, but never using the result that it returns?

Comment: @brasofilo If I put it before the click function I then get only 1 response out of the 3 so...

Comment: @Barmar I've done that to get a false or true response for the if controle

Comment: That will tell you if the `prepare()` was successful. It doesn't tell you anything about whether the query returned anything. Use `$stmt->num_rows`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I've updated the code in OP and implemented num_rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
var press = $.this.attr('id');
```

It should be either:

```
var press = this.id;
```

or:

```
var press = $(this).attr('id');
```

You also need to assign the result of `$.parseJSON` to a variable:

```
responseText = $.parseJSON(responseText);
```

Or you could specify `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax()` call, and jQuery will automatically parse the response for you.